# PDO fetchColumn() ignores SQL "LIMIT"?

Tags: mysql, pdo, limit

Why is PDO's fetchColumn() ignoring the SQL LIMIT part of my query?

$result returns "2" when there are 2 records found in the database?

Thanks!

```
$sql = "SELECT count(*) FROM table WHERE Username = ? and 
Password = ? LIMIT 1";

$q = $this->connection->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array($user, $pwd));

$result = $q->fetchColumn();
echo $result;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the count may be 2 for the number of records found in the database but that aggregate function only requires one row in which to return the result.  The limit here is actually useless.

In other words, go run that query without the LIMIT on your server and you will see a one row result set with the value of 2 (if there are two such user/password combos in the table that is).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, I see why that's happening now. fetchColumn() isn't doing any counting at all is it! - I'm trying to ensure that only one result is returned for a simple login script, do you know the best way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: I would design that into my table by placing a unique index across the user and password fields.  Therefore you are guaranteed only one result max.

Comment: Each user has a unique ID in the DB design, and there should never be a case where the usernames are the same, let alone the username and password together, however I just want to build in as much security as possible. How would you check for the unique index?

Comment: @CraigWilson You already have a case where there is a duplicate.  You wouldn't check for a unique index, you would need to create one. You should already at least have indexes on those fields anyway. I guess if you are uniquely indexing only the username filed, that should be sufficient (rather than having an index on both fields)

Comment: Thanks. The duplicate is there just for testing, it shouldn't occur in production. So are you saying that the unique "ness" of the fields should be handled by external methods, such as the account registration process, and there is no need to do any explicit checking here?

Comment: I am saying that if you have a unique index on your username field and a regular index on your password field (you should have both of these fields indexed anyway since you are using them in your WHERE clause) that you will have no need to check for duplicates because any attempt to insert a duplicate username into the database table would result in a MySQL error.  The table design itself ensures the uniqueness of the user.